# getting an error on file.createNewFile

Tags: android

I am trying to create the file if it doesn't exist, but I keep getting the error "No such file or directory".  I know I have created the directory, because I see the message "Made the directory".  Help please?

```
Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString()+ 
"/Sheridan_ips/Documents";
  FPath = new File(Path);
  if (!FPath.exists()) {
      if (!FPath.mkdirs()) {
          FPath.mkdirs();
          Log.d("MainActivity", "Made the directory");
      }
  }

  Log.d("MainActivity", "Created the directory");
  try {
      file = new File(FPath, "RSSI.txt");
      Log.d("MainActivity", "After file instantiation");
       if(!file.exists())
       {
           Log.d("MainActivity", "Before file.createNewFile");
           file.createNewFile();
           Log.d("MainActivity", "Created new file");

       }
       Log.d("MainActivity", "Before PrintWriter");
       pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file), true);
       Log.d("MainActivity", "After PrintWriter");
       pw.print(beacon.getRssi());
       pw.print(kalman.kalman(rssis));
       pw.println();
       pw.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat, thanks.

Comment: `FPath.mkdirs()` is supposed to return true if the directory was created. So write this `boolean created = FPath.mkdirs()' and log the value of `created`. Please also include the logcat.

Comment: Do you have a `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: yes I have a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: 05-17 22:24:34.657 8916-9474/ca.sheridancollege.sheridan_ips D/MainActivity: Made the directory
05-17 22:24:34.657 8916-9474/ca.sheridancollege.sheridan_ips D/MainActivity: Created the directory
05-17 22:24:34.657 8916-9474/ca.sheridancollege.sheridan_ips D/MainActivity: After file instantiation
05-17 22:24:34.658 8916-9474/ca.sheridancollege.sheridan_ips D/MainActivity: Before file.createNewFile
05-17 22:24:34.659 8916-9474/ca.sheridancollege.sheridan_ips W/System.err: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you checked on file explorer that it's created or not that particular folder?